# Extract text from several Google docs into Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to extract the text from each Google document in a folder in Drive and paste the text into the first column of a Google spreadsheet so that the contents of file 1 are in A1, the contents of file 2 in A2 etc. Ultimately I am trying to recreate a database of the information stored in all these files, so if the text can be split by field so much the better, but I think this should be trivial in Excel using Text to Columns.

I have used a few snippets online to have a stab at it but I'm now stumped.

Here is my script as it stands:

```
//Function to extract the body from each document in a folder and copy it to a spreadsheet
function extract() {

//Define the folder we're working with ("Communication Passports") and get the file list
var folder = DocsList.getFolder("Communication Passports");
var contents = folder.getFiles();

//Define the destination spreadsheet file (CP) and set up the sheet to receive the data

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AicdFGdf-Cx5dHFTX1R3Wm1RTEFTZ2d5ZmxuSjJSOHc");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
Logger.log('File name: ' + ss.getName()); 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.clear();
sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Date", "Contents", "URL", "Download", "Description"]);

//Set up other variables
var file;
var data;

//Loop through and collect the data (I don't actually need this - just borrowed the code from    a   snippet online - but it is SO CLOSE!)
//Sadly, getBody doesn't work on files, only on documents
for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
file = contents[i];

data = [ 
  file.getName(),
  file.getDateCreated(),
  file.getViewers(),
  file.getUrl(),
  "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=" + file.getId(),
  file.getDescription()
];

sheet.appendRow(data);


//Extract the text from the file (this doesn't work at present, but is what I actually need)


var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
var body = doc.getBody();

//Find a way to paste the extracted body text to the spreadsheet
}
};
```

Any help would be very gratefully received - I'm not a programmer, I'm a teacher and the information is about children's learning needs at our school (someone deleted the database over summer and our backups only go back a month!).

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: Could you show a typical doc's content so we can see what kind of data you need to retrieve?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
body = doc.getBody().getText();
```

to return the actual contents of the document.

I wrote another function to parse the content into more usable chunks and then pass back to an entry in the data table and it worked fine.